# dataframe.set_index; TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a list of Pandas.Dataframe into a list of dictionnaries and trying to use the column "id" as a key for my dic. Not all of my dataframes have an `id` column, so I am checking before and some id columns are not. However, none of my results are using the `id` column as a key:

```
for dataframe in dataframes:
        if 'id' in dataframe.columns:
            cleaned_dic =  dataframe.set_index('id').T.to_dict('dict')
            else: 
            cleaned_dic = dataframe.T.to_dict('dict')
```

*Example result in json*

```
{
  "0": {
    "date": "2020-01-03",
    "id": 9,
    "journal": "Journal of photochemistry and photobiology. B, Biology",
    "title": "Gold nanoparticles synthesized from Euphorbia fischeriana root by green route method alleviates the isoprenaline hydrochloride induced myocardial infarction in rats."
  },
  "1": {
    "date": "01/01/2020",
    "id": 10,
    "journal": "The journal of maternal-fetal & neonatal medicine",
    "title": "Clinical implications of umbilical artery Doppler changes after betamethasone administration"
  },
  "2": {
    "date": "01/01/2020",
    "id": "11",
    "journal": "Journal of back and musculoskeletal rehabilitation",
    "title": "Effects of Topical Application of Betamethasone on Imiquimod-induced Psoriasis-like Skin Inflammation in Mice."
  },
  "3": {
    "date": "01/03/2020",
    "id": "12",
    "journal": "Journal of back and musculoskeletal rehabilitation",
    "title": "Comparison of pressure release, phonophoresis and dry needling in treatment of latent myofascial trigger point of upper trapezius muscle."
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code and data has nothing to do with the title of the question. Please add code and stack trace of the error you got or correct the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the `.set_index('id')` method is failing because it's trying to order the 'id' columns but it finds INTs and STRs.

You should convert the 'id' columns, before using `.set_index('id')`, to make all the values in that series of the same type, INTs or STRs.

You may try doing something like this to your dataframe before setting the index:

```py
# raising errors
df.astype({'id': 'int64'}, errors='raise')
# ignoring errors
df.astype({'id': 'int64'}, errors='ignore')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
d = {}
for dataframe in dataframes:
    d[dataframe['id']] = dataframe.to_dict()
```